# Attaching contact info in sms message

Tags: contacts, sms, 8.0-oreo

When I first got my Moto G, I was able to attach contact info in a message.  Now that it updated its OS, I can no longer do this. How can I attach contact info to an SMS in Oreo?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what version of android you are on, but here is what I just did to share a contact in Android Lollipop 5.0.2. And this solution doesn't have anything to do with lollipop, as it has to do with the People app. The same version is available on 4.0 versions of android as well.

- Open People app
- Select the contact
- click on the "3 dot menu"
- click on "share"
- click on "hangouts" (or your SMS / MMS app)
- clicked on "new message" (or an existing message)
  [image]
- It adds the contact card to the message.
- click send

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Contacts
2. Click on Edit Contact
3. Copy Data to Clipboard
4. Return to SMS App
5. Long Press on Screen
6. Select Clipboard Option
7. Paste Data from Clipboard.

In this way You will be able to add Contact Data as in Text format.